# What is the first cucumber version where "Support for '~@tag' will be removed from the next release of Cucumber" is shown when '~@tag' is used?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there a way to find it out? I tried to read cucumber's for java changelog https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the introduction of tag expressions `"(not @foo and @bar) or @baz"` in v2.0.0 the `"~@foo, @bar", "@baz"` style tags were deprecated. Supported for these deprecated tags has been removed in v5.0.0-RC1.

Answer (score 3):

From the [changelog](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) it looks like this will be removed in v5:

```
5.0.0-RC1 (2019-10-11)
....

Removed
[Core] Remove deprecated tag syntax.
```

Comment: But I'm trying to find out when this message appeared first time, not when was deprecated tag syntax removed.